# Historically, what methods have irregular forces used to disable tanks?

Tags: military, tanks, modern

During the 2022 war between Ukraine and Russia, it [has been reported that Russian tanks have been abandoned due to running out of fuel](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/europe/ukraine-tank-fuel-russia-kyiv-b2024003.html).

Now, I do not necessarily believe this story as news stories from active war zones are notoriously unreliable, but if a civilian or irregular combatant did want to disable a tank to which they had access, what methods have been used historically and what methods are likely to work on a modern tank?

Comment: Put sugar in the fuel tank

Comment: @kimchilover since there is no specific Stack site dedicated to matters military, it has been my experience that they are tolerated here.

Comment: @MCW Very well, question modified to have an historical focus.

Comment: Since its speculative, its possible that WorldBuilding would take a variant of it.

Comment: Actually came across rather a lot of material about this while doomscrolling on twitter the last few days. Shame I didn't think to save any of it for references. The basic gist is that its standard NATO doctrine to keep your logistics train close at hand and very well-defended, since it isn't armored like the tanks. Russia is more into lightning thrusts, which are great if they work. Ukraine has been getting its army a lot of NATO-style training the last 8 years. Put the two doctrines together, and you get Ukrainians letting Russian tanks roll by and going back to take out their fuel trucks.

Comment: @T.E.D. Yes, Twitter has become The Freedom Fighter's Handbook just lately ;-)

Comment: @TheHonRose - It kinda always has been, since back in the early days of the Arab Spring. IIRC, Twitter first became popularized because Tunisian anti-Ben Ali street activists were using it to organize in realtime, and western media followed them to the platform to report on what was going on.

Comment: [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-would-you-disable-a-tank) ,[Wired](https://www.wired.co.uk/article/disable-a-tank), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-tank_warfare)

Answer (score 4):

The [first tanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_heavy_tanks_of_World_War_I#Mark_I) were designed to be proof against rifle fire and rifle-caliber machine guns. Countermeasures included field guns (out of the scope of the question) and [anti-tank rifles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-tank_rifle#World_War_I), either a larger caliber or standard calibers with armor-piercing bullets. Another option were larger-than-normal grenades, e.g. by wiring several heads to a [Stielhandgranate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stielhandgranate#Improvised_%22bundle_charge%22).

Between the world wars, tanks got tougher, and anti-tank cannon around 37mm were introduced (also out of the scope of your question). Anti-tank rifles were still in use at the beginning of WWII, but they were increasingly ineffective. At the end of WWII shaped-charge weapons were developed (also out of scope for your question).

The usual measure for forces without an arms industry was the [Molotov Cocktail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molotov_cocktail), a firebomb made of gasoline, a bottle, and some other components. Tanks have since become *more* resistant to flame, but a burning puddle seeping into the air intakes remains a bad thing.

When one stands next to a tank, and one hasn't been shot by the other tanks in the platoon, it is also an option to try and jam the tracks. Rocks, concrete, or iron bars might damage track elements and running wheels of a *moving* tank. That *may* be an option if unsupposed tanks are sent against a demonstration, and not allowed to shoot indiscriminately. It is not a good plan in battle.

And regarding those supposedly abandoned tanks, one way to deal with tanks is to shoot at their fuel trucks. [Russian tanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-90) have a road range around 500 km with extra fuel drums. In battle, off-roads, the range is much lower.

Comment: If a tank is abandoned, wouldn't it be easy to throw a Molotov INSIDE the tank? Burning all of its equipment and possibly leading to explosion of carried munitions?

Comment: If the tank is abandoned, there is no need to destroy it, but when needed, there are of course many methods to disable it.

Comment: If the tank is abandoned, bring a drum of fuel and you've got your own tank!

Comment: I think that US tanks use turbines to generate electricity to charge a battery, and the treads are run off that battery. Are you certain about the air intake thing?

Comment: @axsvl77, turbine power and electric transmissions are *different* aspects of vehicle design. Both the US and the Soviets have fielded turbine tanks, which have some advantages and some disadvantages over conventional diesel. Electric transmissions are less common. Offhand the WWII *Maus* comes to my mind. And gas turbines have air intakes, too.

Answer (score -1):

Let me add that Ukrainian government is currently publishing on Internet simple recipes for making Molotov cocktails. Another method used by unarmed civilians is to create road blocks from any available material. The main immediate goal is to stop the tanks, even if you cannot destroy them. Destroying fuel tankers is also a very effective mean since a tank without fuel is of little use.

Historically, all kinds of methods were tried, among more exotic ones, delivering of explosives to a tank by specially trained dogs (I know that this was used by the Soviets in WWII from the first-hand sources). But the primary modern tool is a hand-held cumulative grenade launcher; they are cheap and portable.

Comment: It turns out that Molotov cocktails were also part of standard US anti-tank doctrine in WW2 - see this, courtesy of the US taxpayer: https://youtu.be/taHFUKKKmJM?t=576